# C++ Error on Neural Network Implementation: duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, eclipse, linker

Hey guys I'm trying to implement the backpropagation algorithm in C++ and I've tried Xcode and C++ Eclipse but I'm getting the same error and I have no idea how to fix it, I've tried searching here but none of the proposed solution worked, here is the following error message and my code.

Error Message:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/NeuralNet.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/NeuralNet.d" -MT"src/NeuralNet.d" -o"src/NeuralNet.o" "../src/NeuralNet.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/NeuralNet.cpp

Building target: NeuralNet
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++  -o "NeuralNet"  ./src/Net.o ./src/NeuralNet.o   
duplicate symbol __ZN3NetC2ERKNSt3__16vectorIjNS0_9allocatorIjEEEE in:
    ./src/Net.o
    ./src/NeuralNet.o
duplicate symbol __ZN3NetC1ERKNSt3__16vectorIjNS0_9allocatorIjEEEE in:
    ./src/Net.o
    ./src/NeuralNet.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [NeuralNet] Error 1
```

And here is my code:

NeuralNet.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Net.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<unsigned> topology;
    topology.push_back(10);
    Net net(topology);


    return 0;
}
```

Net.h

```
#ifndef NET_H_
#define NET_H_

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Net {
public:
    Net(const vector<unsigned>& topology);
};

#endif
```

Net.cpp

```
#include "Net.h"

Net::Net(const vector<unsigned>& topology) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}
```

Comment: The funny thing is that if I declare the Net class inside the main file and remove the include, the code works. But when I try to separate the file in classes I get this error, but i have no idea why the duplication is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IDE is trying to compile both `.cpp` files as individual compilation units, because usually those contain the individual compilation units.

However you are including `Net.cpp` in `NeuralNet.cpp`, so the code in it (i.e. the implementation of `Net::Net`) is compiled in the unit of `Net.cpp` as well as the unit of `NeuralNet.cpp`.

After compiling both compilation units the linker is called to link them together. It notices that `Net::Net` appears twice and doesn't know which to choose, therefore the error.

You should never `#include` a `.cpp` file. Replace `#include "Net.cpp"` with `#include "Net.h"`. You always include the header (`.h`) for the class, not the source (`.cpp`).

Comment: Okay, but if I remove the #include in the main file I can't make reference to the type Net, what should I do instead ?

Comment: Thanks dude! It worked fine now!! I've been frustated with this the whole day! You rock!!